# Is there an operadic structure to classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, category-theory

Consider a closed system of several particles in motion with a certain eom (equation of motion). We can replace each of these particles with another closed system and produce another classical mechanical system with a well defined eom.

This, to me at least, suggests that there is an operadic structure hiding there.

Q. Is there?

More tentatively, is there a way of characterising classical mechanical systems through operadic means?

Comment: The way you introduce the would-be operadic structure reminds me of the work on compositionality by D. Spivak et al. Maybe it might be helpful to look into their work.

Comment: @NDewolf: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @NDewolf: There's a text by Spivak called *Category Theory of Scientists*. In his last section he mentions operads and uses wiring diagrams as an illustration. No mechanics, unfortunately. Still, thanks for the tip, it was useful.

Comment: The reason why I didn't specifically go into the mechanics part, was that you did not really seemed to use any of the related structures (kinematics / dynamics). Only the fact that you can (de)compose classical systems.